# How to change the default HTML style while rendering in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, epub

I am developing an ePub reader in Android. I am trying to change the alignment and text color in HTML. It's working fine for some ePub books, but not in others, since those books contain the style defined in CSS. I have tried to override those style in Javascript using the following code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign ='justify' !important;"
```

It's not working in Android WebView, but it's working in iPhone. What I am doing wrong here? Is there any other method to override the style? Please help me.

Comment: so are you writing a mobile website or an Android app?

Comment: its an Android app containing webview to load html page.

Answer (score 0):

You could over-ride the shouldInterceptRequest method in a subclass of WebViewClient.  You can use that to intercept CSS load requests and substitute your own CSS data instead.  If you don't always want to completely replace the ePub's CSS, you could use a css parser (like perhaps http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) to parse and then modify the supplied CSS with the changes you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late response. Its working fine as if i over-ride the ShouldInterceptRequest Method. But now the problem is if i over-ride the css the entire css will be overrided i need to override some of the styles only. I couldnt alter the css since its drm protected.whats the solution for this?